rightleftharpoons in "commutative" diagram
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}

and this
$\begin{CD} 
cc              @>a>b>    ct\\ 
@VlVrV     @AlAr          A\\
tc              @<a<b<     tt
\end{CD}$

but I want to replace unidirectional arrows by \rightleftharpoons (and the labels a,b,c, etc by $k_{-1}£ etc but thats okay)
Is there a fix or a better approach available?


Did you try to compile the code you posted? If it doesn't, please correct your post. Thank you

It's rather easy with tikz-cd.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
cc \arrow[r,shift left=1pt,harpoon,"a"] \arrow[d,shift left=1pt,harpoon,"r"] &
ct \arrow[l,shift left=1pt,harpoon,"b"] \arrow[d,shift left=1pt,harpoon,"r"]
\\
tc \arrow[r,shift left=1pt,harpoon,"a"] \arrow[u,shift left=1pt,harpoon,"l"] &
tt \arrow[l,shift left=1pt,harpoon,"b"] \arrow[u,shift left=1pt,harpoon,"l"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}



perfick! thanks

A version with xy package that it is not simple to do.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=2pc{ cc  \ar@<.2ex>@^{->}[r]^a \ar@<-.2ex>@^{_{<}-}[r]_b & ct \ar@<.2ex>@^{->}[d]^r \ar@<-.2ex>@^{_{<}-}[d]_l \\
           tc \ar@<.2ex>@^{->}[u]^l \ar@<-.2ex>@^{_{<}-}[u]_r & tt\ar@<.2ex>@^{->}[l]^b \ar@<-.2ex>@^{_{<}-}[l]_a }
\end{document}


